# Problems with big C# list, list is inaccessible

Tags: c#, list, thread-safety

Every time I do a List.add to one list bigger than 1000, I have a chance to get (Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute). If I increase the size, the problem happens more often. I have a lot of threads making a cache of info, and users getting info on MVC5 by one controler ActionResult JSON.

```
    public static List<int> list = new List<int>();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        new Thread(() => { 

            for (var a = 0; a < 10000000000; a++) 
            {
                Thread.Sleep(50);
                lock (list)
                {
                    list.Add(1);
                    list.Add(1);

                }
            }


        }).Start();
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Index2()
    {
        return Json(new { Response = new { Id = 0, Url = list } },
            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: what is the question? where is the code? where is the error?

Comment: **Collection was modified** happens when you modify collection while enumerating on it, e.g add or remove items to you collection while you are in a `foreach` on that collection.

Comment: The problem is, if I access Index2, when the list is bigger than 1000, I will get Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. many times. And I tried to use Lock(list){}, but dont work.

Comment: @doctor how can I prevent this?

Comment: Let's see... you're locking on a public static variable, which is horrible.  You're locking, but nobody else is, which is worthless. And you're modifying the collection when the Result is being serialized to json (and the list is being enumerated).  It's a DailyWTF level of work here.  How about you initialize your list on startup and then don't touch it afterwards?

Comment: Look into using a thread safe collection: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Why are you filling your list in a separate thread? That makes no sense, other then creating this issue on purpose. Isn't only the for loop what you should do in Index?

Comment: @Will People come to this site for help.  If he's doing things that aren't correct, how about letting him know why and how to fix it instead of being rude and condescending?

Comment: @KyleW I'm a bucket of cold water.  See you at the bar.

Comment: The real project get the info from SQL Server and load like a cash at main project and using WebSockets I send this cash to another ones, so I need anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to lock the variable whenever you're accessing it. Do it like this:

```
public ActionResult Index2()
{
    lock(list) {
    return Json(new { Response = new { Id = 0, Url = list } },
        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```